# Sub Domain's Pages return 404

Tags: 404-error, google-xml-sitemaps

Need some help, I created these websites

```
http://mccsedu.org
http://parents.mccsedu.org
http://faculty.mccsedu.org
http://students.mccsedu.org
```

The main site is working fine, but the pages of the those subdomains are not working. it always returns 404, you can try visiting those sites and click on any posts or pages..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always delete the .htaccess for each root directory, then visit each domain.com/wp-login.php then visit: Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks & save changes. (Automatically generates a fresh .htaccess)

OR

login to phpmyadmin for each domain,

check out the database... options table... verify the "siteurl", and "home" columns. make sure they match the respective domains.

OR

Check the DNS zone template. Could very well be possible DNS conflicts.

Comment: Hey Micheal!! works like charm! so great.. yeah.. Thank you so much..

Comment: @markyeoj Glad you were able to fix it with my solution.